# How to use $unwind in golang?

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I want the result in go as the mongo shell provide me.

In mongo shell the data is like this:

```
db.user.aggregate([{$unwind:"$user"}]).pretty()    
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57307906f051147d5317984e"),
    "user" : {
        "firstName" : "chetan",
        "lastName" : "kumar",
        "age" : 23
    },
    "sales" : [
        {
            "firstName" : "ashu",
            "lastName" : "jha",
            "age" : 27
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57307906f051147d5317984e"),
    "user" : {
        "firstName" : "nepolean",
        "lastName" : "dang",
        "age" : 26
    },
    "sales" : [
        {
            "firstName" : "ashu",
            "lastName" : "jha",
            "age" : 27
        }
    ]
}
```

But in go

```
package main    
import(
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
        "encoding/json"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
        "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
        "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"
)
type User struct{
    FIRSTNAME   string      `json:"firstName" bson:"firstName"`
    LASTNAME    string      `json:"lastName" bson:"lastName"`
    AGE     int     `json:"age" bson:"age"`
}
type Sales struct{
    FIRSTNAME   string      `json:"firstName" bson:"firstName"`
    LASTNAME    string      `json:"lastName" bson:"lastName"`
    AGE     int     `json:"age" bson:"age"`
}

type Details struct{
    ID  bson.ObjectId   `json:"_id" bson:"_id"`
    USER    []User      `json:"user" bson:"user"`
    SALES   []Sales     `json:"sales" bson:"sales"`
}

func detail(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    session, err := mgo.Dial("127.0.0.1")
        if err != nil {
                panic(err)
        }else{
                fmt.Println("dial")
        }
        defer session.Close()


        session.SetMode(mgo.Monotonic, true)

        c := session.DB("userdb").C("user")


       var result []Details


    o1 := bson.M{
        "$unwind":"$user",
    }


        operations := []bson.M{o1}
    pipe := c.Pipe(operations)
    err = pipe.All(&result)
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }
        res1B, _ := json.Marshal(result)
        fmt.Fprintf(w,string(res1B))
}

func main(){
    router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
    router.HandleFunc("/detail",detail)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":9080", router))

}
```

Result is like this:

```
 [{"_id":"57307906f051147d5317984e",
"user":null,
"sales":[{
"firstName":"ashu","lastName":"jha","age":27}]},{"_id":"57307906f051147d5317984e",
"user":null,
"sales":[{
"firstName":"ashu","lastName":"jha","age":27}]}]
```

But it shows `"user": null`, I want the reult as provide by mongo shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the mapping is invalid, after `$unwind` on `$user`, you should expect every single result only contains a single user, therefore, `User` shouldn't be an `array`.

```
type Details struct{
    ID  bson.ObjectId   `json:"_id" bson:"_id"`
    USER    []User      `json:"user" bson:"user"`
    SALES   []Sales     `json:"sales" bson:"sales"`
}
```

Should be changed to:

```
type Details struct{
    ID  bson.ObjectId   `json:"_id" bson:"_id"`
    USER    User      `json:"user" bson:"user"`
    SALES   []Sales     `json:"sales" bson:"sales"`
}
```

Since you might need two types of responses, one is normal response, another one is `$unwind` response which is current one, you can create another type for it:

```
type UnwindDetails struct{
    ID  bson.ObjectId   `json:"_id" bson:"_id"`
    USER    User      `json:"user" bson:"user"`
    SALES   []Sales     `json:"sales" bson:"sales"`
}
```

and remain your original `type`

```
type Details struct{
    ID  bson.ObjectId   `json:"_id" bson:"_id"`
    USER    []User      `json:"user" bson:"user"`
    SALES   []Sales     `json:"sales" bson:"sales"`
}
```

So you got to modify the type of `result` variable to:

```
var result []UnwindDetails
```

Comment: my json file is like that{
 "_id" : ObjectId("57307906f051147d5317984e"),
 "user" : [
  {
   "firstName" : "chetan",
   "lastName" : "kumar",
   "age" : 23
  },
  {
   "firstName" : "nepolean",
   "lastName" : "dang",
   "age" : 26
  }
 ],
 "sales" : [
  {
   "firstName" : "ashu",
   "lastName" : "jha",
   "age" : 27
  }
 ]
}

Comment: Yes you got a list of users, but the problem is `$unwind` will modify the behavior (from an `array` to a single `element`). Another suggestion is to create another `type` for `$unwind` version of response.

Comment: But if i want  to use in array then what to do?

Comment: You can create another type for `$unwind`, lemme update my answer.